# How to shrink pointers (linked with GSL)?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, realloc

I have a problem with my code when I was trying to shrink the allocated memory. The result showed :

```
creating matrix
reallocating matrix (expanding)
defining GSL matrix in new matrix
reallocating matrix (shrinking)
realloc(): invalid next size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

It showed that I have put invalid next size in reallocation method. In my code, I was giving less number of size (shrink the memory). The code I implemented is shown below :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "test.h"
#define nSub 4

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int testSize = 2000;
    double timeOut = 2;
    clock_t start_time;

    gsl_matrix ***c;

    printf("creating matrix\n");
    calloc_matrix_C(&c, nSub, nSub, testSize, testSize);
    // malloc_matrix_C(&c, nSub, nSub, testSize, testSize);
    start_time = clock();
    while ((double)(clock() - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC < timeOut)
        ;

    printf("reallocating matrix (expanding)\n");
    realloc_matrix_C(&c[0], 5);
    start_time = clock();
    while ((double)(clock() - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC < timeOut)
        ;

    printf("defining GSL matrix in new matrix\n");
    c[0][5] = gsl_matrix_calloc(testSize, testSize);
    start_time = clock();
    while ((double)(clock() - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC < timeOut)
        ;

    printf("reallocating matrix (shrinking)\n");
    realloc_matrix_C(&c[0], nSub);
    start_time = clock();
    while ((double)(clock() - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC < timeOut)
        ;

    printf("free the matrix\n");
    free_matrix_C(&c, nSub, nSub);

    start_time = clock();
    while ((double)(clock() - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC < timeOut)
        ;

    printf("done\n");
    while (1)
        ;
    return 0;
}

## Heading ##
void calloc_matrix_C(gsl_matrix ****x, int alloc_dim_1, int alloc_dim_2, int mat_dim_1, int mat_dim_2)
{
    (*x) = calloc(alloc_dim_1, sizeof(double **));
    for (int i = 0; i < alloc_dim_1; i++)
    {
        (*x)[i] = calloc(alloc_dim_2, sizeof(double *));
        for (int j = 0; j < alloc_dim_2; j++)
        {
            (*x)[i][j] = gsl_matrix_calloc(mat_dim_1, mat_dim_2);
        }
    }
}

void realloc_matrix_C(gsl_matrix ***x, int new_dim)
{
    (*x) = realloc(*x, new_dim * sizeof(double *));
}

void free_matrix_C(gsl_matrix ****x, int alloc_dim_1, int alloc_dim_2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < alloc_dim_1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < alloc_dim_2; j++)
        {
            gsl_matrix_free((*x)[i][j]);
        }
        free((*x)[i]);
    }
    free((*x));
}
```

Should the new size be greater?

Comment: `****x`, hmmmm it seems strange to me here

Comment: It is extremely rare that you need 4 levels of indirection in C. In C++ it is so rare that I'd call it a a sure sign that you need to rethink your data structure.

Comment: Please tag only the language that you are actually using/compiling against. Since I didn't see anything specific to C++ (and actually the infinite loop at the end of `main` is technically undefined behavior specifically in C++), I removed the `c++` tag.

Comment: Actually it is certainly not C++, because `calloc` without pointer cast will not compile in C++.

Comment: In `c[0][5] = gsl_matrix_calloc(testSize, testSize);` should that be be 4 instead of 5?  You've allocated 5 elements, so the max index is 4.

Comment: You seem to confuse pointers to pointers (to pointers …) with a matrix. What do you mean by _"defining GSL matrix in new matrix"_? How big do you think the _new matrix_ and the one you're _defining_ is? What is `nSub`?